# How to write this LINQ with foreach in a better way

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I was doing project in MVC3 with Entity framework. I have a LINQ query with foreach. Everything is fine. But when the data size goes up, i was facing performance issues. I dont have much experience with LINQ. So I couldn't fix my issue. Pls have a look at my code and provide a better suggestion for me.

**Code**

```
        List<int> RouteIds = db.Cap.Where(asd => asd.Type == 3).Select(asd => asd.UserId).ToList();

        var UsersWithRoutingId = (from route in db.RoutingListMembers
                                  where RouteIds.Contains(route.RoutingListId.Value) && route.User.UserDeptId == Id
                                  select
                                      new RoutingWithUser
                                      {
                                          UserId = route.UserId,
                                          RoutingId = route.RoutingListId
                                      });

        var ListRouteValue = (from cap in db.CareAllocationPercents
                              where cap.Type == 3
                              select new UserWithDeptId
                              {
                                  Year = (from amt in db.CareAllocations where amt.CareItemId == cap.CareItemId select amt.Year).FirstOrDefault(),
                                  UserId = cap.UserId,
                                  UserDeptId = (from userdept in db.Users where userdept.Id == cap.UserId select userdept.UserDeptId).FirstOrDefault(),

                              });

        List<UserWithDeptId> NewRouteList = new List<UserWithDeptId>();
        ListRouteValue = ListRouteValue.Where(asd => asd.Year == Year);

        foreach (var listdept in ListRouteValue)
        {
            foreach (var users in UsersWithRoutingId)
            {
                if (users.RoutingId == listdept.UserId)
                {
                    UserWithDeptId UserwithRouteObj = new UserWithDeptId();
                    UserwithRouteObj.UserId = users.UserId;
                    UserwithRouteObj.Year = listdept.Year;
                    UserwithRouteObj.UserDeptId = db.Users.Where(asd => asd.Id == users.UserId).Select(asd => asd.UserDeptId).FirstOrDefault();

                    NewRouteList.Add(UserwithRouteObj);
                }
            }
        }
        NewRouteList = NewRouteList.Where(asd => asd.UserDeptId == Id).ToList();
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You have to use join in first statement. Examples of how to do this are for example here: [Joins in LINQ to SQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/03/12/joins-in-linq-to-sql.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have some idea for you:
First:
Take care to complete your where close into your linq query to get just what you need to.
With Linq on collection, you can remove one foreach loop. I don't know the finality but, i've tryied to write something for you:

```
var UsersWithRoutingId = (from route in db.RoutingListMembers
                                      where RouteIds.Contains(route.RoutingListId.Value) && route.User.UserDeptId == Id
                                      select
                                          new RoutingWithUser
                                          {
                                              UserId = route.UserId,
                                              RoutingId = route.RoutingListId
                                          });

            var ListRouteValue = (from cap in db.CareAllocationPercents
                                  where cap.Type == 3
                                  select new UserWithDeptId
                                  {
                                      Year = (from amt in db.CareAllocations 
                                              where amt.CareItemId == cap.CareItemId && amt.Year == Year
                                              select amt.Year).FirstOrDefault(),
                                      UserId = cap.UserId,
                                      UserDeptId = (from userdept in db.Users 
                                                    where userdept.Id == cap.UserId && userdept.UserDeptId == Id  
                                                    select userdept.UserDeptId).FirstOrDefault(),

                                  });
List<UserWithDeptId> NewRouteList = new List<UserWithDeptId>();

            foreach (var listdept in ListRouteValue)
            {

                var user = UsersWithRoutingId.Where(uwri => uwri.RoutingId == listdept.UserId).FirstOrDefault();
                if (user != null)
                {
                    NewRouteList.Add(new UserWithDeptId { UserId=user.UserId, Year=listdept.Year, UserDeptId=listdept.UserDeptId  });
                }
            }

            return NewRouteList
```

Is that right for you ? 
(i don't poll the db.user table do get the UserDeptId for the NewRouteList assuming that the one in the listdept is the good one)

Second:
Take care of entity data loading, if you have tables with foreign key, take care to remove the lazy loading if you don't need the children of your table to be loaded at same time. Imagine the gain for multiple table with foreign key pointing to others.
Edit:
Here is a link that explain it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456846%28v=vs.100%29.aspx